How could I make a thick sketchy outline around metaballs used in a particle effect?
I am trying to recreate the cursed energy effect from Jujutsu Kaisen. I have the shape of the energy down by using metaballs as the particle. I also almost have the material down but I'm still trying to make the inside of the particles more transparent then the outside but that's besides the point.
I have tried many ways to outline and I've had varying results, I couldn't get inverted hull to work on meta balls, using grease pencil gives me weird lines in places I don't want and I couldn't get that to work properly.
The only thing I've tired that worked was freestyle.
I wondering if I can get one of the looks of the outlines in Jujutsu Kaisen (The very blotchy thick messy one or the more controlled almost painted look(this is the one in the picture)) using freestyle, or if there's another way to do it.

